# How can i hide my data from sniffing?

Tags: delphi, indy, sniffing

I use this code to connect to fileserve.com using my premium account i want to share my program but they can easly snif username and password using "HTTP Analyzer" is there a way to hide my username and password from sniffing ?i use delphi 2007.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i:integer;
  Data, Page : TStringList;
begin
  IdHTTP1.OnRedirect := nil;
  IdHTTP1.AllowCookies := True;
  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
  IdHTTP1.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
  IdHTTP1.CookieManager := IdCookieManager1;
  IdHTTP1.RedirectMaximum := 15;
  IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)';

  Data := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Data.Add('loginUserName=[user]');
    Data.Add('loginUserPassword=[pass]');
    Data.Add('autoLogin=');
    Data.Add('loginFormSubmit=Login');
    IdHTTP1.Post('http://www.fileserve.com/login.php', Data);
  finally
    Data.Free;
  end;

  IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := False;
  IdHTTP1.OnRedirect := IdHTTP1Redirect;
  IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.fileserve.com/file/aYkRqp3');

  Edit1.Text := idHTTP1.Response.Location;
  for i := 0 to IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.Count - 1 do
    Memo2.Lines.Add(IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.Items[i].CookieText);
end;
```

Comment: I think you're violating part 7(n) of Fileserve's usage terms. You can use FileServe to distribute that program, but you can't let all your customers use your account to download. Let your users provide their own account information if they want fast download speeds. Or find a hosting provider better suited to your needs. Or just link to the program's Web site and don't worry about distributing it yourself at all.

Comment: i'm not going to break ther T.O.S i just wanna learn programming and share my program with my friends

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the code above could be analyzed without sniffing the HTTP packets; all someone would need to do is look at the strings contained in the binary itself, and they'd find your ID and password.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to hide bits you're transmitting from sniffing.  The only thing you can do is encrypt the bits so that even if someone gets ahold of them, they can't figure out what they mean.  See if the website you're connecting to has an HTTPS version available, and try using that (and Indy's HTTPS protocol handlers) instead of the HTTP version.

Comment: The site doesnt support HTTPS thats so sad, thanks for your info

Comment: HTTP is much easier to intercept than you think, BTW :)